# Change text style with mat-slide-toggle

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can I change the style of a text using Ang-Material-2's mat-slide-toggle?

[image]

```
<mat-slide-toggle [color]="primary" [checked]="true">Slide me</mat-slide-toggle>
<h3>Text</h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a class or style property to the `<h3>` element based on the toggle's state:

```
<mat-slide-toggle #toggle [color]="primary" [checked]="true">Slide me</mat-slide-toggle>
<h3 [ngClass]="{'primary-color' : toggle.checked}">Text</h3>
```

CSS:

```
.primary-color {
    color: red; // you should use theming to access the theme's primary color
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Just one detail if I wish that by default this `checked:"true"` I get the following error: `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'primary-color: false'. Current value: 'primary-color: true'.`
How can i fix this?

Comment: I'd need to see a complete example. Please create a stackblitz.

Comment: @g-tranter https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9twrl when it starts by default in `true`, the error is observed.

Comment: Since the switch is bound to `item.state`, you can also bind the class to `item.state` instead of `toggle.checked` - data bound properties are a far better way to handle this anyway.